# IDEA console output going to same file for different run/debug configurations?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, logging

I created two run/debug configurations for my multi-module maven project:

- `build1` does clean:install skipping tests
- `test1` is the same but runs the tests

On the `Logs` tab, I set each to a different console output file, then exited. I ran `build1` first and `test1` second, but only had ***one*** output file. When I checked, the `build1` configuration was pointing at the `test1` output file! I tried enabling `Store as a project file` for both but that didn't work.

If I exited and immediately went back into `Edit Configurations...`, the output filenames for both configurations were set to whichever config I edited last. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annoying problem, simple solution. This odd behavior occurs when you create one run config, then highlight it and click `Copy Configuration`. Changes to most (or all?) other items in the cloned config will stick ***except*** console output file. You decide whether this is a feature or a bug...

The fix is to click the plus sign (`Add New Configuration`) and enter a different console output file. Of course, you also have to enter all the other config info, which defeats the clone config functionality ::sigh::